# Is there a way to convert a complex JSON to an object without creating a POJO?

Tags: java

I want to convert a JSON-String to an object. Normally I create an POJO and convert the String  to a `GSON` or `JSONObject` to my POJO. But is there a better where I don't have to create an POJO?

The goal is to get an object where I can access the keys and values of the JSON... in whatever way, like jsonObject.getKey("foo").getProperty("bar").. or whatever :D

Comment: Better in what way? You either have a `String`, a POJO, or a `JSONObject` (or the corresponding type for different libraries).

Comment: What kind of object do you want it to be?  A String is an object.  So is a POJO.

Comment: You can do that now; what's the issue?

Comment: `JSONObject` (or the corresponding type depending on library) already lets you do that. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky Good point, thanks. I edited the questions. See last paragraph.

Comment: +1 for `JSONObject` is what you want

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis really? I must check that. That would be awesome :D

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Normally GSON, because it's said that it's more advanced. But I acrtually have no idea if it really is.. for my case.

Comment: You can check the package name. For GSON, it should be `com.google.gson.JsonObject`, you may also have `org.json.JSONObject`

Comment: Bothe of them are what you want. See the [GSON doc](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) and [org.json doc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: Thank you guys. Deleting this question, since it seems too stupid.

Comment: Undeleted because of @SotiriosDelimanolis answer.

Comment: You mean like use a JSON parser??  Like JSON.simple?  (I second going to json.org and studying the JSON syntax.  A JSON "object" is the same as a Java Map, and a JSON "array" is the same as a Java List.  It's very simple if you don't complicate it with Jackson and the like.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most JSON parser/generator libraries have a type for each of the [JSON types](http://json.org/).

Gson has `JsonElement` and its sub types. Here's an example where you can chain calls.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String jsonString = "{\"property1\":\"someValue\", \"arrayProperty\":[{\"first\":1234, \"second\":-13.123}, {\"nested\":\"so deep\"}], \"finally\":\"last\"}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonElement.class);
    System.out.println(element);
    JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject(); // should test type before you do this

    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("arrayProperty").getAsJsonArray().get(0));
}
```

prints

```
{"property1":"someValue","arrayProperty":[{"first":1234,"second":-13.123},{"nested":"so deep"}],"finally":"last"}
{"first":1234,"second":-13.123}
```

The above is more or less implemented with a `LinkedTreeMap` for `JsonObject` and a `List` for `JsonArray`. It provides wrappers to access the elements as more `JsonObject`, `JsonArray`, `JsonNull`, and/or `JsonPrimitive` instances.